# What are some real-world use of some unusual SQL Server data-types?

Tags: sql-server, sqldatatypes

What are the following SQL Server data types used for?

Give me some real-world examples.

1. `binary(50)`, `varbinary(50)` and `varbinary(max)` instead of image
2. `smallint` and `tinyint` instead of `int` and `bit`
3. `varchar(50)` and `varchar(max)` instead of `text`
4. `sql_variant`
5. `uniqueidentifier`

Comment: The variety of types in MSSQL is due to Microsoft's philosophy of "if some idiot wants it, we sell it to him", tying the poor guy to a proprietary platform.

Comment: @Philip: To clarify your prejudice, are you "anti-MS", "anti-propriety" or "anti-non-standards-compliance"?

Comment: @gbn: hehe, I pick "anti-non-standards-compliance", though I wouldn't call me exactly "anti". There are always cases where standards don't supply enough choices, but IMO the solution is to extend the standard instead of introducing home-brew solutions. Sadly, it usually works the other way around, but even then it's possible to agree that custom extensions are marked as such, as e.g. with CSS extensions where some vendors occupy their own namespace as in `-moz-*` and `-webkit-*`. I can hardly imagine a scenario where it's a good idea to *remove* parts of the interface.

Answer (score 6):

1. [image is deprecated and also very limited](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx) (MSDN)
2. You can't compare bit with the rest. tinyint/smallint: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/4979/630
3. text is deprecated and very limited (as point 1)
4. Multi-language support in one column: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/10009/630
5. Merge replication: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1164694/27535

Comment: `4` is commonly used in EAV scenarios as well.

Comment: EAV == Entity Attribute Value

Answer (score 3):

1)

> varbinarymax instead of image

`image` is deprecated, so you need to use `varbinary(max)` to ensure compatibility with future SQL Server versions

2)

> smallint and tinyint instead of int and bit

These are four different types that store numeric values with different ranges. It depends on the data you want to save in that column:

- if you need only 0 and 1, use `bit`
- if you need no more than 0 to 255, use `tinyint`
- if you need no more than -32768 to 32768, use `smallint`
- if you need more, use `int`

Of course you can use `int` for everything, but the "bigger" types also need more space per row. So if you only need 0 and 1 values, it makes absolutely no sense to use an `int` column, because it will only unnecessarily grow your database.

3)

> varchar(50) and varcharmax instead of text

Same as 1): `text` is deprecated, so you need to use `varchar(50)` or `varchar(max)` to ensure future compatibility (and if your text will always fit into 50 characters, it doesn't make sense to use `text` or `varchar(max)` anyway).

5)

> uniqueidentifier

To store [GUIDs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187942.aspx)

Comment: @Saqib: I didn't mention `sql_variant` in my answer on purpose because  I don't know anything about it (honestly, I never heard about it before I read your question). But the link in [gbn's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8702375/6884) looks quite good to me.